# A question about completely positive map

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a unital C*-algebra and $\phi: A\rightarrow M_{n}(\mathbb{C})$ be a completely positive map. If $P$ denotes the projection onto the kernel of $\phi(1_{A})$ and $P^{\perp}=1-P$ is the orthogonal complement.

My question is: can we conclude that 
$$\phi(a)=P^{\perp} \phi(a)= \phi(a)P^{\perp}$$
for all $a\in A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for any cp $\phi:A\to B(H)$. If $x\in \ker \phi(1_A)$, then for any $a\in A$, 
$$
\|\phi(a)x\|^2=\langle \phi(a)^*\phi(a)x,x\rangle\leq\|\phi(1_A)\|\,\langle\phi(a^*a)x,x\rangle\leq\|\phi(1_A)\|\,\langle\phi(\|a^*a\|\,1_A)x,x\rangle\\=\|\phi(1_A)\|\,\|a\|^2\,\langle\phi(1_A)x,x\rangle=0.
$$
So $\phi(a)P=0$ for all $a\in A$. This implies that $\phi(a)P^\perp=\phi(a)$ for all $a\in A$. As this holds for all $a\in A$ and we can take adjoints, we also have $\phi(a)=P^\perp\phi(a)$.

This idea works even if you don't assume that the codomain of $\phi$ is $B(H)$. What I mean is that if $\phi(1_A)T=0$, then $\phi(a)T=0$ for all $a\in A$. Indeed, 
$$
(\phi(a)T)^*\phi(a)T=T^*\phi(a)^*\phi(a)T\leq \|\phi(1_A)\|\,T^*\phi(a^*a)T\leq \|\phi(1_A)\|\,\|a\|^2\,T^*\phi(1_A)T=0,
$$
so $\phi(a)T=0$.

Comment: In your first inequality, do you use the Kadison inequality? I think Kadison inequality holds if $\phi$ is a contractive c.p.

Comment: You are right, but it doesn't hurt the argument because all that is needed is a $\|\phi(1_A)\|$. I'll edit right now.

Comment: I still do not know why does your first inequality hold.

Comment: It is called "Kadison's Inequality", or sometimes "Schwartz Inequality" and it holds for all completely positive maps: $\phi(a)^*\phi(a)\leq\|\phi(1_A)\|\,\phi(a^*a)$.

Comment: @Marin Argerami Oh, yes. Thanks.